# Java: Assign Scanner input to multiple variables?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm doing old codeforces problems for practice, and a pattern I repeat often in Python is:

```
(m, n, k) = [int(i) for i in raw_input().split()]
```

to quickly assign `m, n, k` because inputs such as

```
4 2 7
```

are common in codeforces as a first input line. Is there any way I can do this kind of thing (with multiple variables `m, n, k`) quickly in Java (preferably 1-2 liner)?

Any help appreciated (or link to somewhere that answers the q). Thanks!

Comment: No, you have to write three separate statements for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way I can think of is like so:

```
    System.out.println("Enter values:");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    int j = scan.nextInt();
    int k = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print(i + " " + j + " " + k);
```

Input: 1 2 3

Output: 1 2 3

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you're wanting, IMO, it's a close substitute if you store the input in an array.  You don't have three "separate" variables per say, but a 1 - 2 liner as you're requesting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 3 values separated by spaces: ");
    int[] mnk = Arrays.stream(input.nextLine().split(" "))
            .mapToInt(a -> Integer.parseInt(a)).toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mnk));
}
```

The other "downside" to a method like this, is that the input is SO restrictive to integers being entered and separated by spaces.  There is no way you're going to get a 1 - 2 liner with error checking.

Results:

```
Enter 3 values separated by spaces: 4 2 7
[4, 2, 7]
```